# Is "Tramonti" Italian?

Tags: translation

Is "Tramonti" Italian? I'm not sure. I went to google translate, wrote "Tramonti" and it was translated as "sunsets". I know that "Tramonto" is "sunset".

Comment: how come you write it with a capital T?

Comment: “Tramonti” is also a toponym; there are three “comuni” so named: Tramonti (Salerno), Tramonti di Sopra and Tramonti di Sotto (Pordenone). The origin is of course “tra monti”, that is, “between mountains”. As a curiosity, Tramonti di Mezzo also exists, midway from Tramonti di Sotto and Tramonti di Sopra, but is a “frazione” of the former.

Comment: If you know that there's a word ("tramonto") and even if you're unsure that there's such a word, the right way to check all its forms is to look up in a dictionary (and to [see immediately that "tramonti" is the plural form](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/tramonto)). Please next time **first** look up the word in a dictionary, and only if it doesn't answer your question, ask on Italian SE. Thank you for your collaboration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's correct: "tramonti" is the plural of "tramonto".

Most nouns with an "-o" ending will change it to "-i" to indicate plural.

Comment: @Tia27, since you are here to learn Italian, the correct form is “molte grazie”.